# XDocument asynchronous loading options

Tags: .net, async-await, linq-to-xml, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

dotnetcore 2.0 provides these methods for asynchronous loading of XDocument:

```
public static Task<XDocument> LoadAsync(Stream stream, LoadOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
public static Task<XDocument> LoadAsync(TextReader textReader, LoadOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
public static Task<XDocument> LoadAsync(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

However these aren't available in .NET Standard 2.0. As such the options seem to be either do a synchronous load (which might be OK depending on the circumstances), or maybe wrap the synchronous load in an asynchronous task like so:

```
Task.Run(() => { xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader); });
```

But not sure if that gives any benefit over the plain synchronous approach. E.g.  if the code is running in an AppPool process in IIS then the synchronous call is performed on a thread from a thread pool, and if the underlying XmlReader blocks while it waits for IO, then that thread is not returned to the thread pool - which I think *would* be the case with an async/awaitable method such as LoadAsync().

Is my summary correct?

Are there other options to consider?